# writing multiple lines in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm fiddling with javascript to get the hang of it. I am trying to built an x by x grid programatically--which I'll eventually try to get to be minesweeper. I have a function to write a single row with x entries. I have another function that loops, calling the single row function x times. The idea is that by calling the row function x times, I'll get an x by x grid. But in my current code, the looping function is calling the single line function 1 time and I can't figure out why. When I use alerts to count iterations, the loop fires five times--but not when the writeOneRow function is included. I get the same behavior in IE and Chrome. Can anyone point out my (likely bonehead) error:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

function writeRows(loop) {
         for (i=0;i<loop;i++){
             writeOneRow(loop);  //this is only called once. Why?
         }
}

function writeOneRow(num) {
         var b = "<Div style='float:left; border-style:solid; margin:10px'> Test </div>"
         var string =""
         for (i=0;i<num;i++){
             string= string+ b ;
             }
         var line = document.createElement('div');
         line.innerHTML = string ;
         document.body.appendChild(line);
}  
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:writeRows(5);return false;">InsertRow</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your variable `i` is a global. Use `var` to make them local.

```
for (var i=0;i<num;i++){
...
for (var i=0;i<num;i++){
```

Comment: thanks. that worked. I knew it was something dumb. So if you don't declare VAR you get a global variable? Why did that cause the thing to loop only one time?

Comment: also nitpick, your `'Div` should be `<div`

Comment: _Why did that cause the thing to loop only one time?_ Because it is global and `i` is over 5 when the second loop completes. It gets back to the first one and says i==5 so I stop.

Answer (score 2):

My JavaScript is a bit rusty, but you never declare i as a local variable, so I think both for loops are modifying the same i and thus it hits 5 inside the second function and the first loop only runs once.

Try adding var i; in both your functions before the for loops and that will create a local variable in each case and should fix the problem. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but this could help...

Change the line:

```
line.innerHTML = string ;
```

To:

```
line.innerHTML = line.innerHTML + string;
```

Than you won't need the second for loop anymore you could just do:

```
var string = b;
```